# Find the quotient and the remainder of $(n^6-7)/(n^2+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Given that $n$ belong to $\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Find the quotent and the remainder of $(n^6-7)/(n^2+1)$.

So I tried to divide them up and got a negative expression $(-n^4-7)$.

How to continue?

Or what can be done differently?

How to find the quotent and the remainder?

Comment: What is "dish", seems like it was mistranslated?

Comment: $a/b=c$ so c this the dish , I'm sorry about my english .

Comment: It's no problem, I think the word you are looking for is 'quotient'.

Comment: Just curious.  In your language does "dish" literally mean "dish" as in the things you eat out of?  If so, I wonder why they use that term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by "dish" you mean "quotient"; that's not terminology I'm familiar with, but it seems to make sense in context.

When you're dividing polynomials, remember that *you are not done until the remainder is of lower degree than the denominator.* So you're correct that the first step of dividing $n^2 + 1$ into $n^6 - 7$ gives you a remainder of $-n^4 - 7$ (with $n^4$ in the quotient); but since $-n^4 - 7$ is of higher degree than $n^2 + 1$, we have to keep going.

To go into $-n^4 - 7$, we need to multiply by $-n^2$; so now our quotient so far is $n^4 - n^2$, and our remainder is $(-n^4 - 7) - (-n^2 (n^2 + 1)) = n^2 - 7$.

Since $n^2 - 7$ is still at least as high in degree as $n^2 + 1$, we have to divide one more time; this gives us a quotient of $n^4 - n^2 + 1$ and a remainder of $(n^2 - 7) - (n^2 + 1) = -8$.

Since the remainder now has degree $0$, which is less than the degree of our divisor, we can stop now; so **the quotient is $n^4 - n^2 + 1$ and the remainder is $-8$.**

Answer (score 2):

We have $n^6-7 = (n^2+1)q(n)+an+b$, with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, because $n^2+1$ is monic.

Plugging $n=\pm i$, we get
$$
-8 = \pm ai+b
$$
which implies $a=0$ and $b=-8$. Therefore,
$$
q(n) = \frac{n^6-7+8}{n^2+1} = \frac{n^6+1}{n^2+1} = n^4 - n^2+ 1
$$
Thus,
$$
n^6-7 = (n^2+1)(n^4 - n^2+ 1)-8
$$

Comment: What process did you do?

Comment: @arthurAdinayevProject, see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

$$  \left(   x^{6}  - 7 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{6}  - 7 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  + 1 \right) } +  \left( -8  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  =  \left( -8  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  - 1 }{ 8 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  + 1 \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   x^{4}  -  x^{2}  + 1 \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  - 1 }{ 8 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  -  x^{6}  + 7 }{ 8 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  -  x^{2}  - 1 }{ 8 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  - 7 \right)  \left( \frac{ 1}{8 } \right)  -  \left(   x^{2}  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{  x^{4}  -  x^{2}  + 1 }{ 8 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$

---

Answer (score 0):

I was going to answer your question exactly in the way [**lhf**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf) have done, just explaining the process in my post. Firstly, if we divide a polynomial $f(n)$ by another polynomial $g(n)$ of lesser degree, we will have a remainder $h(n)$ such that, $\text{deg(}h)< \text{deg(g)}$. $$f(n)=g(n)\cdot q(n)+h(n)~~~~\cdots (1) $$ as, if you have term with power higher or equal to $\text{deg(}g)$ then, you can fit it in the polynomial $q(n)$, so, you will always get such an unique $h(n)$, and we call this $h(n)$ as remainder polynomial.

Now, if we divide the given polynomial $n^6-7$ by $n^2+1 $ then we have remainder with degree atmost $1$(as, $\text{deg(}n^2+1)=2$. Hence, it will be of the form $an+b$. $$n^6-7 = (n^2+1)\cdot q(n)+an+b~~~~~~~\cdots (2)$$

Now, the only information that will help us to find the remainder are the roots of $(n^2+1)$, $n=\pm i$, as we don't know what is $q(n)$, the roots will help to vanish the first term of equation $(2)$. The first term will be zero $($we are choosing the roots of $n^2+1$$)$ and we will left with second term only of equation $(2)$ and we will get the following equations:
$$ai+b=-8\\-ai+b=-8$$
which gives, $a=0,b=-8$. So, $$n^6-7=(n^2+1)\cdot q(n)-8\implies n^6-7+8=(n^2+1)\cdot q(n)$$ factorizing we get, $n^6+1=(n^2)^3+1=(n^2+1)(n^4-n^2+1)$. Hence, $q(n)= n^4-n^2+1$. Finally we get, $$n^6-7=(n^2+1)\cdot (n^4-n^2+1)-8$$

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:
$$
\begin{align}
n^6-7 &= \big(\left(n^2\color{red}{+1}\right)\color{red}{-1}\big)^3-7 \\
 &= \left(n^2+1\right)^3-3\left(n^2+1\right)^2+3\left(n^2+1\right)-1 -7 \\
 &= \left(n^2+1\right)\big(\left(n^2+1\right)^2-3\left(n^2+1\right)+3\big) - 8 \\
 &= \left(n^2+1\right)\left(n^4-n^2+1\right) - 8
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\bmod n^2\!+1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n^2\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, n^6\equiv (\color{#c00}{n^2})^3\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^3\equiv -1$  so $\,n^6-7\equiv -8$ is the remainder,

hence the quotient is $\ \dfrac{(n^6-7)-8}{n^2+1} = \dfrac{n^6+1}{n^2+1} = n^4 - n^2 + 1$